# Transfer file between virtual pc 2007 - windows ce and the host OS?

Tags: windows-ce, virtual-machine, virtual-pc

I have a windows ce image install in Virtual PC 2007, it is a VHD-file named HPCF-CEPC-CE5.vhd.
The system works ok, but I need to transfer my application (.exe) to the virtual pc but I can`t, I tried to install Virtual Machine Additions but isn`t work, I tried a network connection but isn`t work and try to connect from activesync through com1 but guest what? isn`t work....

does anybody know how to transfer a file between the windows ce in virtual PC 2007 and my win xp host??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's effectively a separate machine, so (assuming it has network capability in the OS) you can [use CoreCon to manually make a connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then use a tool like the Remote File Viewer (installed with Studio 2005/2008).

Answer (score 0):

[WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/) allows you to open a vhd, copy and paste files to Windows. If you want to get [vmadditions.iso](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963713.aspx) (FSHARE) installed in your vhd, you need to download the VPC 2004 version.